# admin : search custom fields

Tags: admin, search

One year ago @t31os answered a post with a code I can't access:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-custom-field-data

His answer...
I was feeling adventurous, so i wrote a simple plugin to do it..
http://wordpress.pastebin.ca/1736605

The post search in the admin will now also check against the meta keys and meta values when checking for matching posts... ;)

Is there a way to get that code so I can use it?

Thank you very much

Patricia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what's wrong with that link but you can see an answer to a similar question

[how to filter post listing (in WP dashboard posts listing) using a custom field (search functionality) ?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field/16641#16641)

Its just what you are looking for.