# Custom post type admin search

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, search

Is it possible to search in custom post type meta fields? I have posts, with many custom meta fields. Wordpress by default search only in title and in content. How can I change it?

**If you didn't understand what I am saying, please take a look at my [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8228019/wp-search.PNG).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to [**how to filter post listing (in WP dashboard posts listing) using a custom field (search 
functionality) ?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field/16641#16641)

Its just what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to just show specific custom fields? Take a look at the image - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8228019/custom.PNG

Comment: Yep just change the the options of the dropdown and set them manually