# filter custom post type by meta key in dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, search, dashboard, meta-query

I'm looking for a way to expand e customize more this topic

[How to filter post listing (in WP dashboard posts listing) using a custom field (search functionality)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field)

I've a custom post type in the dashboard i've managed to have a small search box with a fixed search function to search a specific meta key. The things is that the search form appears on all the /edit.php pages while i need it only in the specific custom post type edit.php page.

I tried with

```
if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'product')
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Martino, could you add some code to show us how you added the search box? Cheers!

Comment: Actually, it's obvious you are following the method in the linked question :D. See posted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've used the method in the question linked to and are using the `restrict_manage_posts` filter.

```
 add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_search_box' );
 function my_search_box() {
     // only add search box on desired custom post_type listings
     global $typenow;
     if ($typenow == 'product') {
       //On custom post type 'product' admin page.
       //Add code for search box here
     }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast.


It works, I hacked it a little more to filter it only by a specific meta_key.

Could be useful to post the whole code, but I don't know how, I'm new here and the comment section is too small. http://pastebin.com/A3kSD57v

Comment: No problem! Please remember to mark correct answers by ticking them though :D