# Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values

Tags: custom-field, admin, filters

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field/16641) is very close to what I am looking to do, but instead I would like to specify a specific custom field and display a select menu of its available values. Thanks!

Comment: @soulseekah isn't is legal to ask for directions before trying stuff?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Simple to do, first create the dropdown with just the meta values you want and then catch the submit of the filter, just change `POST_TYPE` to the name of your post type and `META_KEY` to the name of your meta key:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Filter BY Custom Fields
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: answer to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45436/2487
Version: 1.0
Author: Bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/

add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );
/**
 * First create the dropdown
 * make sure to change POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type
 * 
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    //only add filter to post type you want
    if ('POST_TYPE' == $type){
        //change this to the list of values you want to show
        //in 'label' => 'value' format
        $values = array(
            'label' => 'value', 
            'label1' => 'value1',
            'label2' => 'value2',
        );
        ?>
        <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
        <?php
            $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
            foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                printf
                    (
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}


add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
/**
 * if submitted filter by post meta
 * 
 * make sure to change META_KEY to the actual meta key
 * and POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type
 * @author Ohad Raz
 * @param  (wp_query object) $query
 * 
 * @return Void
 */
function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'POST_TYPE' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'META_KEY';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Im having trouble getting this to appear on my custtom type post page (type=contestentry). Could you check my functions.php code please? Is this taken from an existing plugin?

http://pastebin.com/BJMua8nq

Comment: You didn't change the `POST_TYPE` here try this: http://pastebin.com/tabUfh3Y

Comment: Works! Thanks @Bainternet! The $type = 'post'; on line 65 had to be changed as well. Thanks again!

Comment: :) The only one you did'nt need to change, it's there for default, but that's OK too.

Comment: Any idea how to remove the SHOW ALL DATES filter completely so that only my custom filters are showing for a given post type?

Comment: @RailsTweeter ask it as a new question.

Comment: Is this still the best way to do that with WP 4 ?

Comment: @mike23 I have a few sites with this same code and all is still working just fine.

Comment: note you may want to make sure it is only ran on the main query `$query->is_main_query()`

Comment: SUPER DUPPER! Thanks!!! If there a way to set some to default filer? Like when I open the list, some filter already selected and the list loads with filter?

Comment: This answer works a treat on WordPress 4.9.5! It's aged very nicely, thank you!

Comment: Great solution! Tks!

Comment: Is `wose45436` a typo or is it intentionally different from `wpse45436`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using another query inside `restrict_manage_posts` make sure you add `&& $query->is_main_query()` to your parse_query if statement, otherwise the parse_query filter will interfere with that second query.

```
if ( 'POST_TYPE' == $type
      && is_admin()
      && $pagenow=='edit.php'
      && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])
      && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != ''
      && $query->is_main_query()
) {
      $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'META_KEY';
      $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add many fields you have to add to query

```
$query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key'     => 'KEY',
    'value'   => $_GET['FIELD'],
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```