# How to add filter in "Comments" at the admin panel?

Tags: admin, comments, filters

I found so many information and most of the tutorials only talk about adding filter in post/custom post only.

I want to do something similar to this tutorial in 'Comments' area in admin panel.

[Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo)

However, I'm not sure if the parse_query handle also handle the query in this area? 
Anyone might have suggestion on tutorial, plugin that might help?

Answer (score 5):

### Working Example <sup>**[Update]**</sup>

From [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72220/12615), by @TheDeadMedic, here's an adaptation to show only comments from a specific `post_id`. A link to this action is inserted in the status row.

`Hello World` is the post with ID 53.

> [image: new comments status link]

When clicked it displays only the comments of that post in the URL
`example.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=all&hello_world=1`:

[image: show comments of only one post]

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wpse_72210_comments_exclude_lazy_hook', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Delay hooking our clauses filter to ensure it's only applied when needed.
 */
function wpse_72210_comments_exclude_lazy_hook( $screen )
{
    if ( $screen->id != 'edit-comments' )
        return;
    
    // Check if our Query Var is defined    
    if( isset( $_GET['hello_world'] ) )
        add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'wpse_63422_list_comments_from_specific_post', 10, 1 );

    add_filter( 'comment_status_links', 'wpse_63422_new_comments_page_link' );
}

/**
 * Only display comments of specific post_id
 */ 
function wpse_63422_list_comments_from_specific_post( $clauses )
{
    $clauses->query_vars['post_id'] = 53;
}

/**
 * Add link to specific post comments with counter
 */
function wpse_63422_new_comments_page_link( $status_links )
{
    $count = get_comments( 'post_id=53&count=1' );

    if( isset( $_GET['hello_world'] ) ) 
    {
        $status_links['all'] = '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all">All</a>';
        $status_links['hello'] = '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all&hello_world=1" class="current">Hello World ('.$count.')</a>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $status_links['hello'] = '<a href="edit-comments.php?comment_status=all&hello_world=1">Hello World ('.$count.')</a>';
    }
    
    return $status_links;
}
```

---

### Useful Hooks

Search for the hooks bellow, they are available in the file `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php`.

It'll give you a panorama of the possibilities for the Comments screen.

### Actions

- [`manage_comments_custom_column`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=manage_comments_custom_column)
- `manage_comments_nav`

### Filters

- [`comments_per_page`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=comments_per_page)
- `comment_status_links`
- `admin_comment_types_dropdown`
- [`comment_edit_pre`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=comment_edit_pre)
- `comment_row_actions`