# How to Auto Approve Comments on a Specific Page?

Tags: theme-development, comments, filters

I am using WordPress comments on a page as a Contact page and I am able to show those comments only to logged in admin.

Now I would like to automatically have any comments placed on my Contact page approved. So, in the front end, I can see all comments placed on that page instead of seeing only the approved comments.

I would love to have a hook in functions.php that works with twenty eleven child theme.

Comment: Why don't you use a contact form plug-in, like Contact Form 7?

Comment: Well I simply believe that if well use the comments function has everything needed and I just want to have the ability to have the contacts save for later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that in `Settings > Discussion` you have this options checked:

[image: comments moderation and whitelist options]

<sup>The first is `comment_moderation` and the second `comment_whitelist`.</sup>

Then, it is possible to selectively disable them using the filter [`pre_option_(option-name)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name)), as follows:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_moderation', 'wpse_72990_auto_aprove_selective' );
add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_whitelist', 'wpse_72990_auto_aprove_selective' );

function wpse_72990_auto_aprove_selective( $option ) 
{  
    global $post;
    if( $post->ID == 2 ) 
        return 0;

    return $option;
}
```

Comment: You save my day.

Comment: Now my next idea is to separate comments of my contact page from other comments by displaying them through a wordpress theme options or at least putting a filter in comments page. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Answered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72108/12615