# Filtering the post list in the admin area

Tags: filters, admin, hooks

How can I filter my custom post type like it's filtered by WordPress itself? By that I mean the links that allow you to show only published, private or trashed posts.

I need it because I want to filter my event post type in a way that you'll only see upcoming events at first, being still able to see all events.

I came across [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo) but it would be a dropdown instead of these links.

[image: filters]

[edit]

So what I want is to have a link `Past events` next to the `Published` link instead of using the standard dropdown menus.

[edit2]

I eventually did use a dropdown, based on this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45447/28916

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `post_submitbox_misc_actions` action as shown in the below example to provide an option for Publish meta-box.

```
<?php

add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'my_post_submitbox_misc_actions' );

    function my_post_submitbox_misc_actions(){
    ?>
    <div class="misc-pub-section my-options">
        <label for="my_custom_post_action">My Option</label><br />
        <select id="my_custom_post_action" name="my_custom_post_action">
            <option value="1">First Option goes here</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option goes here</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

Once used for at-least one post( or a CPT), then those options should appear beside publish actions in all posts admin page.

Comment: If I would go with this approach, I would have to set the event to past manually, right? Can I do the same in a way that's automated, based on the date in the meta data of my post?

Comment: I think this method may not work for what you are asking now.

Comment: If you have no other way, i would suggest using java-script. I am pretty sure you can achieve this.

Comment: Wow, that never even crossed my mind.

Comment: :) Then go ahead... I could give a hand if you need at some point.