# Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values

Tags: filters

Also the same question as here:
[Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo/45447#45447)

But need to search by selecting meta_key and searching by meta_value but not exact value.
Tried to use %search_string% or *search_string* didn't helped.
Any suggestions? (Need to add LIKE param somewhere)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add:

```
$query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = 'LIKE';
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ that helps (and also take a look at the formatting options with the WYSIWYG editor).