# Adding Information To All Posts Screen

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, filters, hooks

What I'm looking to do is add the value of a post's metafield in each post's row on the all posts screen. I'm attaching a screenshot of where I'd like this information to show up. The info would be unique to each post as well. Then I'd like to be able to filter the all posts screen to show only posts with a selected value. Are there hooks/filters available for this functionality to get me going in the right direction? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Add filter menu to admin list of posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo)  Check this out.

Comment: Perfect, so that works great to add the filter to the all posts screen. What I still need to do is find a hook/filter to allow me to add info to each post's row on the same screen.

Comment: Just an FYI in case anyone else is looking for this info, adding custom columns to the all posts screen can be done with the following two filters: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column