# Admin - Search Events by a custom field

Tags: custom-field, search, events

I am using the events manager plugin and i created a new field using custom fields plugin.
I don't know how to make the search from wp-admin to filter using the custom field i added. For details please check the image below.   [image]

I found many posts how to use custom fields to search in posts, but i can't make them work in events.
i printed the data from the field using $EM_Event->output('#_ATT{event_code}')

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo) and see if that is what you're looking for

Comment: Tnx but this doesn't really help me. I found a lot of tutorials for custom fields and posts, but i need to use them with EVENTS MANAGER. :(