# Display Meta Values in Custom Filter - Admin Custom Posts

Tags: posts, filters, wp-admin

I have created a Custom filter for a custom post. I based my code from here - [Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo) and it works just fine.

However, it only lists the titles of the post upon filtering. How can I include the meta values as return values so I can show it beside the post (columns)? Thanks.

Update (here is my code):

```
function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){

    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( ('custom_post_1' == $type || 'custom_post_2' == $type || 'custom_post_3' == $type) && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {

        global $wpdb;
        $search_query = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];

        $custom_key_1 = "custom_key_1";
        $custom_result_1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '$custom_key_1' AND meta_value = '$search_query'");

        $custom_id_1 = array(); 
        if ($custom_result_1) {
            foreach ($custom_result_1 as $value) {
                $custom_id_1[] = $value->post_id;
            }
        }

        $query_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = '$type'");


        $custom_id_2 = array(); 
        if ($query_result) {
            foreach ($query_result as $value) {
                $custom_id_2[] = $value->ID;
            }
        }


        $custom_id_3 = array();

        foreach ($custom_id_2 as $id) {
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $id, 'custom_value_1' );
            foreach ($meta_value as $key => $value) {
                if (in_array($value, $custom_id_1)) {   
                    $custom_id_3[] = $id;
                }   
            }
        }

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => "custom_key_2",
                'value' => $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'],
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => "custom_key_3",
                'value' => $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'],
                'compare' => '='
            ),  
        );

        if (!empty($custom_id_3)){
            $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $custom_id_3;
        }
        else{
            $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
```

Comment: Show your code, pls. It'll be a little bit hard to help without seeing it...

Comment: Please show what you've already tried and you're more likely to get useful answers.