# Filter Pages by Custom Field (ACF) in admin area

Tags: filters, wp-admin, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to filter pages in admin area by a custom field created with ACF.

I found a function here ( http://www.iamabdus.com/blog/wordpress/filter-custom-posts-by-custom-field/ ) and I adapted that code to my need.

When I click on "pages" the options load correctly, but when I click on "Filter" even if the filter work good, I receive a Warning: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".
The var_dump($acf_field) return NULL.

I hope I explained the problem...

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );

function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
 $acf_field_name='field_5c65759c23c46';
 $acf_field=get_field_object($acf_field_name);
 var_dump($acf_field);
 $post_type_to_filter='page';
 $type = 'post';

 if (isset($_GET['post_type'])):
  $type = $_GET['post_type'];
 endif; // isset($_GET['post_type'])

 if ($post_type_to_filter == $type):
  foreach($acf_field['choices'] as $field_value => $field_label){
   $values[$field_label]=$field_value;
  }
  ?>
  <select name="custom_field_filter_value">
   <option value="">Filtra per tipo pagina</option>
   <?php $current_v = isset($_GET['custom_field_filter_value'])? $_GET['custom_field_filter_value']:'';
    foreach ($values as $label => $value) :
     printf(
      '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
      $value,
      $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
      $label
     );
    endforeach;
   ?>
  </select>
  <?php
 endif;
}

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){
 global $pagenow;
 $type = 'post';
 if (isset($_GET['post_type'])):
  $type = $_GET['post_type'];
 endif;
 $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['custom_field_filter_value'];
}
```

Comment: Look here for a similar question about [filtering posts in admin panel by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code and modify the custom post name and meta key of acf and it will work.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );
/**
 * First create the dropdown
/** Create the filter dropdown */
function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
    $type = 'movies'; // change to custom post name.
    if (isset($_GET['movies'])) {
        $type = $_GET['movies'];
    }

    //only add filter to post type you want
    if ('movies' == $type){
        //change this to the list of values you want to show
        //in 'label' => 'value' format
        $values = array(
            'label' => 'value1', 
            'label1' => 'value2',
            'label2' => 'value3',
        );
        ?>
        <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
        <?php
            $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
            foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                printf
                    (
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}


add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
/**
 * if submitted filter by post meta

 * @return Void
 */
function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'movies'; // change to custom post name.
    if (isset($_GET['movies'])) {
        $type = $_GET['movies'];
    }
    if ( 'movies' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'META_KEY'; // change to meta key created by acf.
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']; 
    }
}
```

Comment: When you copy the code from someone else's answer, you should at least mention it.

Comment: For reference here is the original answer by @Brainternet : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45447

Answer (score 0):

So I tried Pawan's answer and while it did work, it was applying the filter all over the place, not to the custom post types I wanted.  So I made a slight modification that should make this work:

```
public function filter_exhibitions($post_type, $which) {
  $target = 'exhibition'; // Created this target variable and removed the $_GET stuff

  if($post_type == $target) { // Test for correct post type
    $values = array(
      'Temporary' => 'temporary', // Add your own 'Label' => 'value' pairs here
      'Permanent' => 'permanent',
      'Online'      => 'online',
    );

    ?>
    <select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE">
      <option value=""><?php _e('All exhibition types', 'artlytical-media'); // Change this to the default null value display ?></option>
    <?php
    $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
    foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
      printf(
        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
        $value,
        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
        $label
      );
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_exhibitions' );

function exhibition_posts_filter($query){
  global $pagenow;

  if(is_admin()) {
    $type = $query->query['post_type'];
    $target = 'exhibition';

    if($type == $target &&
      $pagenow == 'edit.php' &&
      isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) &&
      $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '') {
      $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'exhibition_type'; // Change to meta key created by acf
      $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']; 
    }
  }
}

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter' );
```