# Backend search; include CPT meta?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-admin, search

I've currently got a Custom Post Type with 2 part titles; I've got everything working perfectly on the front end. But when it comes to searching for a post, the post you're searching for doesn't always show up because part of the title is in the meta for that post.

**Is there any way that I can include the meta in the back end search for the Custom Post Type?**

Comment: This answer might be helpful to you. It doesn't answer your question about how to include the meta in your search but it at least lets you filter by it. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but the following should work:

```
add_action( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse110779_filter_admin_search', 10, 2 );
function wpse110779_filter_admin_search( $pieces, $query ){
      global $wpdb;

     //Check if this is the main query,and is a search on the admin screen
     if( $query->is_search() & $query->is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){

          //Collect post types & search term
          $post_types = $query->get('post_type');
          $search = $query->get('s');

          //Check if query is for 'my-cpt' post type
          if( 'my-cpt' == $post_types 
               || ( is_array(  $post_types ) && in_array( 'my-cpt',  $post_types ) )
          ){

             //Set up meta query
             $meta_query = array( array(
                'key' => 'my_key',
                'value' => $search,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));

             //Generate sql
             $meta_sql = get_meta_sql( $meta_query, 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID', $query );

             $pieces['join'] . = " ". $meta_sql['join'];
             $pieces['where'] . = " OR (" . $meta_sql['where'] .")";
          }
     }
     return $pieces;
}
```

*Please note this **completely** untested, but should work in principle, and will atleast get you started*.

Comment: Hey, I played around with this, but failed to get it to work. Seems pretty similar to Stefano's approach ( http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen ), which works much better, although it does create duplicates for certain searches.