# Enahanced search for edit.php and custom post type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to enhance search capability for edit.php and custom post type of an existing plugin. I thought WooCommerce had an enhanced Search but I haven't been able to locate the code for it.

Basically, I want to add the ability of searching some post_meta and custom taxonomy. For example:

```
@some_meta_key=some_meta_value
```

This would return results where a post's post_meta values are LIKE the one specified for a given key. I would also like to search for post ID and post author, etc.

Has anyone done this before that can point me in the right direction on which hooks I need to use and how I would setup the query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the search context in the admin list post screen](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen)

Comment: Or: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110779/backend-search-include-cpt-meta